# BeautifulSoup and Selenium cannot find div or text on website

Tags: javascript, python, selenium, beautifulsoup

I am trying to use BeautifulSoup or Selenium to get the Head to Head text or its div on betexplorer (link below) but efforts have been fruitless. If I view the source on chrome by hitting ctrl+U, I can clearly see it. But going to VsCode and then running the script below does not seem to show the text nor the div on the dumped source.

Here is my code

**BeautifulSoup version**

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests 

def getlistings(listingurl):
    headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:52.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/52.0'} # fetching the url,
    response = requests.get(listingurl, headers=headers) 
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, "html.parser")
    print(soup)

getlistings("https://www.betexplorer.com/soccer/armenia/first-league/shirak-gyumri-2-lernayin-artsakh/E3lQ7tzK/")
```

**Selenium version**

```
from Selenium import webdriver

import time

driver=webdriver.Firefox()

driver.implicitly_wait(3)

driver.get("https://www.betexplorer.com/soccer/armenia/first-league/shirak-gyumri-2-lernayin-artsakh/E3lQ7tzK/")

js = driver.page_source

print(js)
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Check out https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help to see how to format code blocks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am assuming you want what is between `<head>` and `</head>`.  You can get this with `.get_attribute('innerHTML')`.  Commented out the original answer as I was mistaken about what you mean "Head to Head" lol. See the update.

```
from Selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

import time

driver=webdriver.Firefox()

driver.implicitly_wait(3)

driver.get("https://www.betexplorer.com/soccer/armenia/first-league/shirak-gyumri-2-lernayin-artsakh/E3lQ7tzK/")

#head_inner_text_element = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//head")
#head_inner_text = head_inner_text_element.get_attribute('innerHTML')

#print(head_inner_text)

a = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//ul[@class='list-tabs list-tabs--secondary']//li//span[contains(text(), 'Head-to-head')]")))

print(a.text)

click_mutual = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable(
(By.XPATH, "//div[@id='mutual_div']//a[@href='javascript:void(0);']")))
click_mutual.click()
```

[image]

Comment: same problem. It is not working. I will appreciate if you go to the website, scroll down to a sub heading called 'Head to Head'. That is the div head I am trying to get. Your code simply printed out some javascript and undesired html from the page. I do not know why getting the tag or the text for this website is a biggg problem. Thanks for the effort though

Comment: Wow. It worked. Although you forgot to 'uncomment' the driver.get. Could you guide me in understanding the code better? I plan to get the div id in 'Head-toHead', then click on the show mutual matches on the page. Please, point me to required resources. Thanks

Comment: @asklearner I attached an image. The div containing "Head-toHead" does not have an `id` attribute. I'll add a few lines to click the mutual matches link.

Comment: Thanks Jortega. I have figured it out.